# How to solve issue/errors of fourier command?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am studying Fourier transform through a book of Alex Palamides, and it states that there is a property of Fourier transform, due to which convolution of two time domain signals is equal to inverse Fourier (product of Fourier transforms of signals).

But when I try to put this concept to MATLAB as demonstrated in the book, I get the error shown below, although I have wrote exactly the same code as on page 312 of the book:

[image: Screenshot of error]

My code is as follows:

```matlab
syms t w                         % defining symbolic variables
x1=heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-2);  % defining input1
x2=heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-4);  % defining input2
X1=fourier(x1,w);                % taking fourier transform of input 1
X2=fourier(x2,w);                % taking fourier transform of input 2
right =ifourier(X1*X2,t);        % taking inverse fourier transform of product(which is equal to covolution between signals

ezplot(right,[0 8])              % plotting output/answer
```

Comment: The reason why you get errors and not the author is likely differing matlab versions.

Comment: Do you have symbolic tool box installed?

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message into your question. Never post images of text. Images are not searchable and not accessible to everyone. Thanks!

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? `ezplot` is deprecated, they recommend you use `fplot`.

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2015a

Comment: @fstop_22  yes I have Symbolic Math Toolbox  installed version 6.2